# What is "first modify" in the following piece from a license text?

Tags: terminology, legalese, software

"You may redistribute the source code of this program subject to the condition that you do not first modify it in any way"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'First' is used to mean 'beforehand', so a condition for redistributing the source code is that you don't alter it before redistribution.

Comment: is it the same as "it is not allowed to distribute modified source code"?

Comment: Yes, though it's ALSO saying that you MAY distribute unmodified source code.